# FIX for October CMS install failing on "building configuration files"

Tags: php, xampp, octobercms

On installing October CMS, I ran into an error in which the installation just failed on "**Building configuration files**", with an **Progress failed** notification telling me to check the install.log.

Install.log only revealed that the installation failed at "**Install step: setupConfig**", which didn't really tell me anything I didn't know. Unsure of even what to Google.

Using PHP 8.0.2 via xampp 8.0.2.

Comment: you can answer your own question rather than posting the answer in question description

Comment: @Kristian I suppose that is an option as well, but mostly I wanted to get the info out there for anyone who may have faced the same error as I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from the helpful users on the [OctoberCMS Discord](https://discord.com/invite/gEKgwSZ):

**October CMS doesn't seem to be compatible with this PHP 8.0.2.** If you have recently updated PHP, scale back down to 7.4.15.

The installation finally worked for me when I uninstalled & installed back down to PHP 7.4.15 (xampp 7.4.15).